# Attacking several browser/OS combinations with only one link

Tags: malware, trojan

I’m relatively new to this topic so forgive what may be an obvious lack of understanding.

Say that an attacker had a malicious website whose objective was to plant a Trojan into the device of the user who clicks on a particular link.

Assuming that the website could be accessed by various browsers and/or operating systems, and that they only wanted to include one malicious link in the website, would they be confined to targeting only one browser/OS combination? Or could several Trojans be included in one link, each targeting a different browser/OS combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser provides to every visited website a string identifying itself and your OS, in the `User-Agent` header.

A website could use that information to provide the appropriate file. It is quite common on normal software that the download you are offered is the one matching your system.